# How to intercept a mouse signal in a QComboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a custom combo box placed on a QDialog widget, and I can not catch any of the mouse signals. I sub classed QComboBox to intercept two signals not provided by QComboBox: LostFocusEvent and mouseDobleClickEvent. LostFocusEvent works well but the combo is not firing the mouse events. I need three signals on the combo box and only one suitable is provided.

I tried to set combo.grabMouse(), disregarding the documentation warnings, and the combo.doubleClicked start working, but all other widgets connected through signals start behaving erratically.
Also tried combo.view().doubleClick.connect with similar results. Also I tried other mouse events with similar results (Press- Release- etc)
Finally, I tried to to use event instead of QMouseEvent in the comboBox sub class, but it's intercepted by the focusOutEvent slot.
Mouse event work on QPushButtons including double click on QTableView widgets
Using Windows 8 Python 3.7 PyQt5.

```
`class Agreement(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,db, address, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent= None)
        self.parent = parent
.......................................

    def setUi(self):
    .....................................
        self.comboSupplier = ComboFocus.FocusCombo(self)
        self.comboSupplier.setMaximumSize(220,30)
        self.comboSupplier.setEditable(True)
        #self.comboSupplier.grabMouse()
        self.comboSupplier.activated.connect(self.supplierChange)
        self.comboSupplier.focusLost.connect(self.supplierFocusLost)
        self.comboSupplier.doubleClicked.connect(self.editContact)
    ...........................................

     def supplierChange(self):
        try:
            row = self.comboSupplier.currentIndex()
            idx = self.comboSupplier.model().index(row,0)
            self.supplierId = self.comboSupplier.model().data(idx)
            self.agreementTitle[0] = self.comboSupplier.currentText()
            self.setAgreementTitle()
            self.okToSave[2] = int(self.supplierId)
            self.okSaving()
        except TypeError as err:
            print('supplierChange' + type(err).__name__ + ' ' + err.args[0])

    @pyqtSlot()
    def editContact(self):
        try:
            c = Contacts(self.db,self.comboSupplier.currentText(), 
                APM.OPEN_EDIT_ONE, self.supplierId,parent=self)
            c.show()
            c.exec()
        except Exception as err:
            print(type(err).__name__, err-args)

    @pyqtSlot(ComboFocus.FocusCombo)
    def supplierFocusLost(self, combo):
        try:
            self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
            name = combo.currentText()
            if combo.findText(name) > -1:
                return
       ........................................

class FocusCombo(QComboBox):
    focusLost = pyqtSignal(QComboBox)
    focusGot = pyqtSignal(QComboBox)
    doubleClicked = pyqtSignal(QComboBox)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self,event=QMouseEvent.MouseButtonDblClick):
        print("double click detected")

        self.doubleClicked.emit(self)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if event.gotFocus():
            self.focusGot.emit(self)

        elif event.lostFocus():
            self.focusLost.emit(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cb = FocusCombo()
    cb.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'd like to double click on the comboBox to open a widget to edit the contact attributes on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set QLineEdit to editable, a QLineEdit is added, so to track your events you must use an eventFilter:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class FocusCombo(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    focusLost = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QComboBox)
    focusGot = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QComboBox)
    doubleClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QComboBox)

    def setEditable(self, editable):
        super(FocusCombo, self).setEditable(editable)
        if self.lineEdit() is not None:
            self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.lineEdit():
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                self.doubleClicked.emit(self)
            """elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                print("press")
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                print("release")"""
        return super(FocusCombo, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self,event):
        print("double click detected")
        self.doubleClicked.emit(self)
        super(FocusCombo, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if event.gotFocus():
            self.focusGot.emit(self)

        elif event.lostFocus():
            self.focusLost.emit(self)
        super(FocusCombo, self).focusOutEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    cb = FocusCombo()
    cb.addItems(list("abcdef"))
    cb.setEditable(True)
    cb.doubleClicked.connect(print)
    cb.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If I understood your explanation, when setting the comboBox to editable, a new QLineEdit is added and this is the reason for placing an event filter? It makes sense. I'll try it!

Comment: @Erick Exactly, that is what I point out and implement in my answer

Comment: Two more questions regarding @eyllanesc answer:1.-: Where editable at 'def setEditable' cames from?; 2.-: It does not emit twice, one at 'eventFilter' and again at 'mouseDobleClickEvent'?

Comment: @Erick 1) I did not understand this question. 2) the mouseEvent are normally consumed by the upper widget, in this case the QLineEdit consumes it and therefore the QComboBox is not notified.

Comment: your answer works perfectly. I could figure it out where editable came from and regarding my question of emitting the signal twice, for an unknown reason to me, it does it only once which is what I was looking for.